# Android - Error Code 11 when importing Sqlite Database on Galaxy Note

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using the code below to import a prepopulated (ORMLite) database from assets.

This works just fine on multiple devices, except on a Galaxy Note 10.1. Here I get an exception when the DB is closed after the operation is finished:

"error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line ...."

When I download the database from the device and open it in SqliteBrowser everything seems to be fine. Any ideas ?

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// {....}

public void importDB() {

    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("DBName.db");

    try {
        close();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(), dbPath));
        try {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            for (int n; (n = is.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
    getWritableDatabase().close();
}
```

Error:

```
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database         corruption at line 48171 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/app_name/databases/DBName_db
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/app_name/databases/DBName_db
E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): sqlite3_exec - Failed to set synchronous mode = 1(Normal) 
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database corruption at line 48171 of [ed759d5a9e], db=/data/data/app_name/databases/DBName_db
I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): sqlite returned: error code = 11, msg = database disk image is malformed, db=/data/data/app_name/databases/DBName_db
E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(684): CREATE TABLE android_metadata failed
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(684): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/app.name/databases/DBName.db
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(684): deleting the database file: /data/data/app.name/databases/DBName.db
```

Comment: I do not know how well it will tie into ORMLite, but there is a standard implementation of the package-the-DB-in-assets pattern, in the form of `SQLiteAssetHelper`: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Its would definitely not  be an easy fit as ORMLite provides its own helper class OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper. Thanks for the tip tough.

Comment: Is this repeatable or a one-time event? Anyway: I wonder about thos two close() statements in your code. At this point of time the database doesn't exist anyway, right? Are they necessary? And finally: Which line causes this problem? The `getWritableDatabase().close()`?

Comment: its reproducable every time I try to initialize the DB on the Note10.1. the first close() is just a precaution but not required. the database is created by ormlite when the app is first started. the error is thrown on getWritableDatabase().close().

Comment: See also this blog post: http://techblog.dorogin.com/2011/05/sqliteexception-database-disk-image-is.html Maybe this helps you detect the problem of what got corrupted.

Comment: Don't know how ORMlite works. But shouldn't it just work with the file - after the file was created?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same trouble in android 2.

Comment: No, we just used a different brand for this project, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to sync: `os.getFD().sync()` before closing the FileOutputStream. This has to do with the filesystem. Some do write when they see fit - and this can cause trouble.

Comment: Thanks, thats very useful although it didn't fix the error. I added the error log to the post

Answer (score 0):

As you could observe from logcat output you do not provide a custom implementation for DatabaseErrorHandler and implicit handler (DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler) simply delete the corrupted database. You should use your implementation of DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler

You should run PRAGMA integrity_check; on restored database. This usually return string "ok", if else you could parse the string and for example if you find an index you could drop and recreate it.

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(final Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, new DatabaseErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onCorruption(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                //your code
            }
        });
    }

    // {....}

}
```